# Sort HTML table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is an example code for table sorting taken from javascript.info:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5xHStBMfV5AVtoxR?p=preview&preview=

```
let sortedRows = Array.from(table.tBodies[0].rows).sort((rowA, rowB) => rowA.cells[0].innerHTML.localeCompare(rowB.cells[0].innerHTML));

table.tBodies[0].append(...sortedRows);
```

My question is: `Array.from(table.tBodies[0].rows)` produces an array. But `cells[0]` is not defined for arrays. How does the code work?

Comment: `rowA` is a `Row` ... which has a `.cells` property

Comment: Why do you think it's not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rowA is a TR, so you will have to use fetch cells from it. Array.from just converts an HTML collection/ NodeList to an Array of elements so that you can use Array methods

```js
let sortedRows = Array.from(table.tBodies[0].rows)
  .sort((rowA, rowB) => {
    const cellsA = rowA.querySelectorAll('td')
    const cellsB = rowB.querySelectorAll('td')
    return cellsA[0].innerHTML.localeCompare(cellsB[0].innerHTML)
  });

table.tBodies[0].append(...sortedRows);
```

```html
<table id="table">
<thead>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Age</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Pete</td><td>Brown</td><td>15</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Ann</td><td>Lee</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Data based approach:**

```js
const data = [
  { name: "John", surname: "Smith", age: 10},
  { name: "Pete", surname: "Brown", age: 15},
  { name: "Ann", surname: "Lee", age: 5},
]

const sortData = (key) => {
  return data
    .slice()
    .sort((a,b) => {
      return typeof a[key] === "string"
        ? a[key].localeCompare(b[key])
        : a[key] - b[key]
    });
}

const createTable = (data) => {
  return data.map((item) => {
    return `<tr>${
      Object.values(item)
      .map((value) => `<td>${value}</td>`)
      .join("")
    }</tr>`
  }).join("").concat("<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>")
}
const renderTable = (data) => {
  document
    .getElementById('table')
    .querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = createTable(data)
}

document
  .querySelector('.actionPanel')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const text = e.target.textContent.toLowerCase();
    renderTable(sortData(text))
  })

renderTable(data)
```

```html
<div class='actionPanel'>
  <button>Name</button>
  <button>Surname</button>
  <button>Age</button>
</div>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Age</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: An alternate would be to save data and generate table dynamically. That way, you need to sort data and recreate table. That is simpler and can also work on complex data/ conditions

Answer (score 2):

The `.rows` property of a table gives you an HTMLCollection of the rows in the table. `Array.from` turns the HTMLCollection of rows into an array of rows.

With

```
.sort((rowA, rowB) => rowA.cells[0] ...
```

Each parameter is one of the array items being iterated over - a row - neither `rowA` nor `rowB` are the array that was created with `Array.from`. They're the array elements, which are rows.

The array elements (which were originally the HTMLCollection elements) are still rows - and rows have a `.cells` property.